# Line in, while still going?

Tags: android

I have a while loop that goes while a BuffedReader still has data, what the while loop is meant to be doing is reading each line and then continuing on. This is what I have

```
final BufferedReader in;
....
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
String line = null
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.replace(" ", ",");
    reply.append(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    Log.d("DeviceActivity",  line);
}
```

- Edit

This reads the two lines that are expected and then it doesn't finish the loop like it is meant to.

I have tried it with different inputs as well but same result, it doesn't exit the while loop.

Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Also its not always two lines, it could be infinite.

Comment: What do you mean "*should be there but then it just stops and it doesn't carry on*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This here works, it will only read the line if the input stream is ready.

```
while (in.ready() && (line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.i("Line", line);
    publishProgress(line);
    Thread.sleep(25);
}
```